# How can I tell if vim was called with a filename?

Tags: vim

I'd like to add a switch in my .vimrc to do one thing if vim is being started up to edit an existing file or a new, empty buffer. In other words, I want to know if the command line call looked like this:

```
> vim
```

or this:

```
> vim myfile.txt
```

Is there a flag, argument, or file list I can examine to get this information?

Comment: Let me guess: do you want to open NERDTree automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to check `ifeq (argc(),0)`. http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#argc%28%29